# Remove custom header with @Transformer annotation

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to know if it is possible to remove a custom message header, with @Transformer annotation.

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
public Message transform(Message message) {
    HeaderFilter filter = new HeaderFilter("privateKey");
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you can do that via `remove` function:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
public Message transform(Message message) {
    return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).removeHeader("privateKey").build();
}
```

You don't need any other logic in this method.

On the other hand you can use `HeaderFilter` instead:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
@Bean
public HeaderFilter headerFilter() {
    return new HeaderFilter("privateKey");
}
```